# How do I install the correct dependences for Pillow on Heroku

Tags: heroku, python-imaging-library, apt

A package (`landingai`) I'm using in my Heroku Flask app seems to require Pillow which in turn has [external dependencies](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#external-libraries), so that when I first simply added the package to my app's requirements I got

```
RequiredDependencyException:
             
The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
```

I then did as advised and added the [apt buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt) with

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku-community/apt
```

and added an Aptfile containing `zlib` (as `zlib1g-dev`) which eliminated the `zlib` error — as expected — but exposed a similar one for `jpeg`:

```
RequiredDependencyException:
             
The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
```

But adjusting my Aptfile to have the contents

```
zlib1g-dev
libjpeg8-dev
```

fails to fix the missing `jpeg` error as I would have expected.

How do I install the necessary dependences for Pillow on Heroku?

---

Note: adding all of the dependencies listed in the Pillow documentation to my Aptfile results in entirerhly different and obscure errors, FWIW:

```
             /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/build_89f994d5/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjp2.a(j2k.c.o): warning: relocation against `stdout@@GLIBC_2.2.5' in read-only section `.text'
             /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/build_89f994d5/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.a(jcapimin.c.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `jpeg_natural_order' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```